# Headless Exception in wildfly

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, wildfly, wildfly-8

I'm trying to develop an application which involve me show my log to my supervisor, on deployment on wildfly app server i'm getting Headless Exception.

```
9:26:45,480 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./RealStreamer: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./RealStreamer: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.awt.HeadlessException
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:219)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.start(UndertowDeploymentService.java:72)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:207) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:536) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:181) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at com.prodigy4440.sever.ServerJFrame.<init>(ServerJFrame.java:28)
    at com.prodigy4440.sever.Hook.contextInitialized(Hook.java:27)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:190)
    ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems your application needs some Xserver resources : maybe you are generating images or stuff like that.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/HeadlessException.html
Maybe you should run in headless mode : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html or install a graphic server (maybe just the libs iirc).

Comment: i have tried setting the headless property from a static block, but still get the exception. System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");

Answer (score 0):

you have to use -Djava.awt.headless=true from your command line.

Comment: By default headless is true in wildfly